# apache2 fails to start due to regex

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, regex

I recently enabled mod_proxy for apache2, and after having restarted my server from a power outage, the following error arose whenever I attempted to start apache2:

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                  
Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Regex could not be compiled
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Line 39 contains the following:

```
 <ProxyMatch *>
```

I tried reading the error.log file but could not find any information regarding this error.

Apache2 was functional (with these exact settings) before the server was suddenly shut down. My question of course is: how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the `ProxyMatch` directive takes as its parameter a regular expression.  `*` by itself is not a regular expression -- `*` simply means, "the previous character zero or more times".  So a regular expression that matches everything would look like this:

```
<ProxyMatch .*>
```

That's "any character" (`.`) zero or more times (`*`).

Note that the `Proxy` command uses glob-style matching, so this is valid:

```
<Proxy *>
```

My guess is that this is what you meant.

For more information

- `ProxyMatch` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxymatch
- `Proxy` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy